# Golang Tls X509KeyPair

Tags: go

I use client certificate to connect the server. I don't want to load cert and private key from file. If I don't add "\n" after "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and before "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" then `tls.X509KeyPair([]byte(clientCertificate), []byte(clientKey))`  gives me this error: "panic: tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input". I don't want to add "\n" to cert and private key string, is there another way to implement this?
This is my code:

```
    certpool := x509.NewCertPool()  
    certpool.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(cACertificate))
    var cert tls.Certificate
    
    cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair([]byte(clientCertificate), []byte(clientKey))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    cert.Leaf, err = x509.ParseCertificate(cert.Certificate[0])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            certpool,
        ClientAuth:         tls.RequestClientCert,
        ClientCAs:          nil,
        InsecureSkipVerify: false,
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }
```

above code is a function with parameters:'clientCertificate', 'cACertificate' and 'clientKey'  are coming as string from db.

Comment: Can you share how you initialize `clientCertificate` and `clientKey`?

Comment: edited the question: 'clientCertificate' and 'clientKey' are coming as string from db.`

Comment: PEM encoding is a line delimited format, so if you want to use PEM, you'll need the line returns.  How are you getting the rest of the content?  It likely already has "\n" embedded as well for the base64-encoded part.

Comment: The newlines after the begin and before the end marker are integral part of PEM encoding. It's not optional.

Comment: make sure while storing in database the newline should be included else it will always through an error.  And you don't need to add it manually while fetching from db. You can cross check it for better understanding by adding spaces before BEGIN and after END.